# How to show that f / f' has a removable singularity at 0

Tags: analysis, singularity

I'm new to complex analysis and am not sure where to start with this. The question states:

Let the origin be a pole of order *m* > 0 of an otherwise analytic function *f* of a complex variable. Show that *f / f'* has a removable singularity at *z*=0.

Would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is otherwise analytic, we can expand $f$ as a Laurent series

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-m}^\infty c_kz^k,\;\;\;\;f'(z)=\sum_{k=-m}^\infty kc_kz^{k-1}$$

The pole is of order $m$, so $c_{-m}\neq 0$. This gives us

$$\frac{f(z)}{f'(z)}=\frac{\sum_{k=-m}^\infty c_kz^k}{\sum_{k=-m}^\infty kc_kz^{k-1}}$$

We multiply the top and the bottom by $z^{m+1}$ to get

$$\frac{f(z)}{f'(z)}=z\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{k-m}z^k}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k-m)c_{k-m}z^k}$$

The fraction on the right is continuous at $0$, so its limit as $z\to 0$ is $-\frac{1}{m}$. Since this limit exists, the limit of the whole function  is $0$, since the first piece (namely, $z$) goes to $0$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense, and explained so simply.